# not able to get the driver version pyodbc

Tags: python, django, pyodbc

Unable to start Django application due to pyodbc error

```
django.db.utils.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

i have tried printing the driver used but do net get any driver info

```
import pyodbc
print(pyodbc.drivers())
```

this is the result of the above

```
['SQL Server']
```

this is connection string

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'dbname',
    'HOST': 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
    'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': 'pass',

    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        'timeout': 1000,
    }
```

any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your connection string.

Comment: i have the same setup on a different pc and it is working fine, i am quite sure that something is wrong with the installation and not connection string

Comment: So pyodbc can only see a single driver named "SQL Server" yet your application specifies a driver named "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server". Try using `'driver': 'SQL Server',` instead.

Comment: @GordThompson i have tried that but got the same error.